# JavaFX stop Label overlapping parent?

Tags: java, javafx, label

in JavaFX I am trying to stop the Label from overlapping the parent. This happens when the parent is resized to a size that is lower then the label. In this circumstance I would expect the Label to start to be hidden, but it just shows over the parent's bounds a little bit.

You may use the following FXML to test this out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>


<AnchorPane minHeight="500.0" minWidth="500.0" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="558.0" style="-fx-background-color: black;" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65">
  <children>
      <AnchorPane layoutX="110.0" layoutY="102.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: red;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="15.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="15.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="15.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="15.0">
         <children>
            <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="238.0" layoutY="201.0" style="-fx-background-color: gray;" text="Testing to see if this overlaps" textFill="WHITE" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="5.0">
               <font>
                  <Font size="37.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Note that adding a bottom Anchor to the Label will fix this issue, but I would like to not use that. Is there any work around or fix for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can offer some crutch. Add to label MinHeight and MaxHeight and add to pane heightProperty listener.

Main.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane minHeight="500.0" minWidth="500.0" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="558.0" style="-fx-background-color: black;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Controller">
    <children>
        <AnchorPane fx:id="pane" layoutX="16.0" layoutY="15.0" style="-fx-background-color: red;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="15.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="15.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="15.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="15.0">
            <children>
                <Label fx:id="label" alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="54.0" minHeight="0.0" style="-fx-background-color: gray;" text="Testing to see if this overlaps" textFill="WHITE" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="5.0">
                    <font>
                        <Font size="37.0" />
                    </font>
                </Label>
            </children>
        </AnchorPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Controller.java:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    Label label;
    @FXML
    AnchorPane pane;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

        pane.heightProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldSceneHeight, newSceneHeight) -> {
            double top_margin = 5;
            double bottom_margin = 5;
            double bound_value = label.getMaxHeight() + top_margin + bottom_margin;
            if (newSceneHeight.doubleValue() < bound_value) {
                if ((newSceneHeight.doubleValue() - top_margin - bottom_margin) >= 0) {
                    label.setPrefHeight(newSceneHeight.doubleValue() - top_margin - bottom_margin);
                }
            } else {
                label.setPrefHeight(label.getMaxHeight());
            }
        });
    }

}
```